# Character strings - Functions like strcpy, strcat

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I am suppose to explain the output and spot and mistakes if any. I am kinda confuse with some of the terms as i just started character strings.

```
int i, val;
char str1[15] = "*";
char str2[10] = "";
```

Initialisation applies to all questions.

```
a. 
strcat(str1,"a1b2c3d4e5");
printf("%s\n",str1);
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
str2[i] = '1';
printf("%s\n",str2);
```

Output: ***a1b2c3d4e5** and **11111111111*a1b2c3d4e5**. For the second printf, why does it contains *a1b2c3d4e5? Is it because the nul(\0) is omitted as the looping does 10 times which is exactly the array size and the 11th array size is not initialized.

```
b. 
strcat(str2,str1);
strcpy(str1,"Hello!");
strcat(str2,str1);
printf("%s\n",str2);
```

Output: Simply ***Hello!**

```
c. 
strcat(str2,"*->+12345");
str2[4] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",str2);
strcat(str1,&(str2[2]));
printf("%s\n",str1);
```

Output: ***->+** for 1st printf because anything after nul is discarded? I need some help for the second printf. Is the statement strcat(str1,&(str2[2])); an error statement? The & shouldn't be applied to an array since it is essentially a pointer itself? Can anyone explain to me this part?

```
d. 
str1[1] = '5';
str1[2] = '6';
str1[3] = '7';
i=1;
val=0;
while (str1[i] != '\0') {
val += str1[i]-'0';
i++;
}
for (i=0; i < val; i++)
str2[i] = str1[0];
printf("%s\n",str2);
```

Some help for part d and e?

```
e. strcat(str1,"ABCDEFGH");
strcat(str2,"abcdefghi");
for (i=0; i < 9; i++) {
if (str1[i] < str2[i])
str1[i] += 40;
}
if (strcmp(str1,str2) < 0)
printf("str1 < str2 \n");
else if (strcmp(str1,str2) == 0)
printf("str1 == str2 \n");
else
printf("str1 > str2 \n");
```

Comment: Regarding the first code snippet (a), you're right. All strings in C must contain the terminator character, or string functions might go out of bounds and that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Did you just dump your entire homework? That's not OK.

Comment: ^^ yeah, it's Monday tomorrow :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'explain for me' homework dump.

Comment: @MSalters I think there's a difference between copying and learning and I don't get grades by doing this and no, this is not my homework. This is just a bunch of practice questions.

Comment: c. You should be able to solve the second part yourself, if I point out that `strcat(str1,str2);` does exactly the same as `strcat(str1,&(str2[0]));`. It might also help to know that `strcat(str1,&(str2[2]));` does exactly the same as `strcat(str1,str2+2));`. You say "The & shouldn't be applied to an array" and it isn't, it's applied to an *element* of the array.

Comment: @WeatherVane hi, thanks I think I got it for part c, essentially it is pointing to position 2 of the character array and will start to concatenate from that position. But since beforehand, position 4 is initialized to be nul, it will just be >+ and strcat with str1 gives `*>+`

Comment: Writing a `'\0'` terminator anywhere before the present one, truncates the string at that point - as I am sure you must know.

Comment: d. is assuming that global data is initialised to `0` and therefore the two strings are terminated by default when you write past the present terminator. It sums the numerical value of the characters (digit `0` is character `'0'`, ASCII `48`), but then writes beyond the bounds of `str2` so is **undefined behaviour** and whatever it outputs, might not be the same tomorrow, or on another machine. It's a very poor example, for both those reasons. Part e. tinkers with the characters in one string then compares the two.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question:

```
int i;
char str2[10] = "";    
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
  str2[i] = '1';
printf("%s\n",str2);  // Output: 11111111111*a1b2c3d4e5.
```

> why does it contains `*a1b2c3d4e5`? Is it because the `'\0'` is omitted as the looping does 10 times which is exactly the array size and the 11th array size is not initialized?

After the `for()`, `str2()` is populated with `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`, `'1'`.  This array is not a string because it does not contain a null character `'\0'`.

`printf("%s\n", str2)` expects `str2` to contain a null character.  Since `str2` fails to meet that contract, the result is *undefined behavior* UB.

The output of `"11111111111*a1b2c3d4e5"` is possible well explained by OP's reasoning, but it is still UB.  That means tomorrow, the output may differ, on another machine, the output may differ, it may crash and burn.  It could be the same `"11111111111*a1b2c3d4e5"` for a different reason each and every day.

> To be clear: as the code does not following meet the C contract, the output could be anything and *for any reason*.